# Display hostname in static HTML page on uhttpd

Tags: webserver, html, docker, uhttpd

I have a docker container running uhttpd and serving a static HTML page. How can I dynamically insert the hostname of the container into the static HTML page? I want to keep the container as lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just have a command that runs as part of the container's startup that generates the static HTML page with the hostname within it.

```
$ cat <<EOF > /path/to/var/www/hostname.html
<html>
<body>
<p>hostname is: $(hostname)</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

This command can be placed in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` assuming you're using a SysV style of startup scripts. If you're using systemd you can also do the same, but you'll need to enable the service:

```
$ sudo service rc-local start
```

This will mark it to run, to make it run per startup:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

If you're using something else, such as Upstart, there are equivalent methods for doing the same things above.

#### References

- [[Solved] systemd services to replace /etc/rc.local{,.shutdown}](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148170)

Comment: Even though I ended up using Apache and PHP, if I had stuck with uhttpd and no PHP I would have done exactly what you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP, you can use the following code:

```
echo system('hostname')
```

This will `echo` the output of the command `hostname`. Please note that the command `system` is disabled on many shared hosts for security reasons.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
echo gethostname();
```

-or-

```
echo php_uname('n')
```

Answer (score 2):

For a static page, the easiest way would be to generate the served page from a template replacing a placeholder with whatever the `hostname` command gives you. Execute that code in the entrypoint of your image.

Comment: Welcome to the U&L Stack Exchange. The current phrasing of the answer is too vague. A fuller explanation on how to configure uHTTPd to achieve solution suggested would improve the answer considerably. See also the [help center article on how to write good answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The following is a webpage that would display the hostname. This shows the function 'inline' for web programming.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo gethostname(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```